# Saving a single color OpenGL texture to a file results in a 64x64 black box

Tags: c++, linux, opengl

This code fragment is meant to create a GL texture with a single color, then save the raw pixel data to disk. I then convert that to PNG using ffmpeg. I have tried multiple ways of generating the texture, and multiple ways of saving the texture data, but the result is always the same - a 1920x1080 image with a 64x64 black box in the corner.  What I expected was a 1920x1080 image of a single color.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Conversion command:

```
ffmpeg -pix_fmt rgba -s 1920x1080 -i texture.raw -f image2 output.png
```

Code:

```
  gpu::gles2::GLES2Interface* gl = GetContextProvider()->ContextGL();
  GLuint texture;
  gl->GenTextures(1, &texture);
  gl->BindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  int width = 1920;
  int height = 1080;
  std::vector<unsigned char> data(width * height * 4, 0);
  for (size_t i = 2; i < data.size(); i += 4) {
      data[i] = 255; // blue channel
  }
  gl->TexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data.data());
  gl->TexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  gl->TexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(width * height * 4);
  gl->ReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer.data());
  std::ofstream file("texture.raw", std::ios::binary);
  file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer.data()), buffer.size());
  file.close();
```

Comment: How do I see why someone has voted to close this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the description for `glReadPixels` from the main documentation here: https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glReadPixels.xhtml.

Essentially `glReadPixels` is for getting the pixels from the current frame buffer, *not* from the currently bound `GL_TEXTURE_2D`. I can't 100% confidently answer without more code and context, but it looks like the code you have there is before anything is actually rendered to the frame buffer and you're only setting things up. It's most likely that you get a black box because the data getting saved to the buffer isn't valid.

Hope that helps.